# How to get object from Django-solo?

Tags: python, django, django-models

I have a Django solo model, and I need to get an object from it

```
class Settings(SingletonModel):
    start_message = models.TextField(verbose_name='/start', null=True, blank=True)
    login_message = models.TextField(verbose_name='inst', null=True, blank=True)


    class Meta:
        verbose_name = "Settings"
        verbose_name_plural = 'Settings'

    def __str__(self):
        return "Settings"
```

I need to get in one case "start_message", and in another "login_message". I read the documentation, but can't find any answer. The last which I tried was

```
print(Settings.objects.get())
```

And I get just 'Settings'

Comment: Because that's what `__str()__` returns. To get a field value, use print(Settings.objects.get().start_message)`.

Comment: I get it, thank's a lot